# Raspberry Pi + Owncloud + Iptables

Tags: iptables, owncloud

I have a Raspberry Pi that I am using to store my private files in a cloud (like dropbox)

I used this whole tutorial for configuring the Pi https://www.pestmeester.nl/

the Ip tables were configured according to the tutorial:

```
*filter 
#  Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accept all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#  Allow all outbound traffic - you can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SMTP access
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT

# Allows pop and pops connections
# -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
# -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allows imap and imaps connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow SSH connections
#  The -dport number should be the same port number you set in     sshd_config
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

#  Log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

#  Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

Iptables -L shows
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             loopback/8           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

and iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri Jun 30 12:43:24 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: "                     --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

now to my problem: in the syslog I have lots of entries like that:

`Jun 30 12:00:46 raspberrypi kernel: [6978137.058941] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:c8:1f:66:21:0d:62:08:00:45:00:01:9b:16:66:00:00:80:11:af:dc SRC=192.168.178.103 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=5734 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391
Jun 30 12:01:10 raspberrypi kernel: [6978160.864968] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:19:99:b5:ec:e0:08:00:45:00:01:9b:47:8b:00:00:80:11:7f:06 SRC=192.168.178.24 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=18315 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391
Jun 30 12:01:10 raspberrypi kernel: [6978160.865463] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:19:99:b5:ec:e0:08:00:45:00:01:9b:6f:9b:00:00:80:11:e3:4d SRC=192.168.178.24 DST=192.168.178.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=28571 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391
Jun 30 12:01:40 raspberrypi kernel: [6978190.866330] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:19:99:b5:ec:e0:08:00:45:00:01:9b:47:8c:00:00:80:11:7f:05 SRC=192.168.178.24 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=18316 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391
Jun 30 12:01:40 raspberrypi kernel: [6978190.866884] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:19:99:b5:ec:e0:08:00:45:00:01:9b:6f:ae:00:00:80:11:e3:3a SRC=192.168.178.24 DST=192.168.178.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=28590 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391
Jun 30 12:01:46 raspberrypi kernel: [6978197.138692] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:c8:1f:66:21:0d:62:08:00:45:00:01:9b:16:6e:00:00:80:11:af:d4 SRC=192.168.178.103 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=5742 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391
Jun 30 12:02:10 raspberrypi kernel: [6978220.883154] iptables denied: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:19:99:b5:ec:e0:08:00:45:00:01:9b:47:8d:00:00:80:11:7f:04 SRC=192.168.178.24 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=411 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=18317 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=391`

from time to time the pi looses its connection and the only thing that restores the connection is  service supervisor restart
could those 2 problems be connected to each other? What could I do to configure the ip tables correctly? With the log with these many entries I am not really able to detect the problem that the owncloud has.

I really hope someone will be able to help me

Answer (score 1):

You can deny the Dropbox broadcasts on your Raspi. The 17500 port is used by Dropbox on an other machine.

So add before the LOG  rule : `-A INPUT -p udp --dport 17500 -j DROP`

Then the raspi will drop the connection without logging them.

Comment: ohhh thank you very much! I would have never thought of the dropbox ... but probably the two problems are not connected. Do you maybe have an idea how i could adress the loss of connectivity that appears from time to time? Its really bad if i am on holidays and have to access my files that are saved on the owncloud in the office

Comment: No, I am sorry, you don't provide enough info. You must check the logs when the Pi loose its connection.

Comment: Ok i will have a look at the logs next time i am at my office. The problem is that I am not able to restart the connection without beeing at the office PC and putting  service supervisor restart  into a cronjob doesnt seem to help. Do you know a way, that I can restart the service by using the cronjob? Restarting the service each 20 Minutes doesnt help when the connection is lost, but entering the command manually does

Comment: I think there is something more important hide in your problem. You need to wait and check the logs. Maybe out of memory, maybe something else, but you will see in the logs. When you restart the service by cron, do you have errors ?